# Finding the method responsible for the redirect

Tags: http, grails

In my grails method i am redirecting the view to-another. Code shown below:

```
def method_1 (){
    redirect action: "act1", params: [param1: 'Hi']

}
```

Now from my Filter class i want to detect that `method_1` was responsible to call `act1`

FILTER

```
myFilter(controller:'Person', action:'act1') {
            before = {
                if (!request.getHeader("referer").contains('/Person/method_1')  ) {
                    redirect(action: 'Can't view this')
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
}
```

In this case `request.getHeader("referer")` returns NULL. So how can i find out which `action` called `act1` ?

UPDATE

```
println request.getRequestURI
                println request.getRequestURL
                println request.getContextPath
                println request.getPathInfo
                println request.getServletPath
                 request.forwardURI
```

Comment: Have you tried looking in request.requestURI? I only ask because of the wording in the documentation indicates it may hold what you are looking for. http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html ... it's a long shot and I can't test it out right now (traveling).

Comment: Yes i did. It gives the current URL only. Not the one that requested it. FYI, i have updated my post with all what i have tried. Nothing works.

Comment: hangong your redirecting from step1 to step2 should you not be posting values from step1 to step2?

Comment: What do you mean by step 1 ? `request.getHeader("referer")` results in NULL. Therefore i can't findout who requested the URL

Comment: what i mean is in method_1 you are redirecting to act1 then in ac1 you wish to capture where it came from - why is it redirecting to it ? try convering method_1 to a form that posts to act1

Comment: Note that you can't really use referer because referer does not necessarily point to the previous action.  There are a number of scenarios where the referer is expected to be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this is to put some state in `flash`:

```
def firstAction (){
    flash.foo = 'firstAction'
    redirect action: "secondAction", params: [param1: 'Hi']
}

def secondAction() {
    if('firstAction' == flash.foo) {
        // do whatever you need to do
    }

    // ...
}
```

When you put something in `flash` it is there for the rest of that request and 1 subsequent request before being cleared.  This makes it useful for holding on to data during a redirect because the redirect will trigger a second request and you want the data to be available during that next request, but not after that.

Comment: The example I showed there is checking the value of `flash` inside of a controller action but of course you could do the same thing in your filter.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Jeff for sorting this out for me.